# Java EE getting information about what environment the application is currently running

Tags: java

You can run a Java EE application in a test environment, a development environment or a production one.

How can I use Java code or XML to get hold of that information?

```
if ( ApplicationContext.inDevelopment() { // do this }
```

Obviously the above is not correct. But you get the point. How can I do this?

Comment: Use the hostname, or set a variable using -D, etc?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to JEE so I have no idea what you are talking about :O ... If I want to be able to get that information using Java code, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to achieve it.

- check ip address of the sever to decide which platform it is running
  on.
- add -D property into your server start script, in your program get
  the system property.
- for different platforms using different properties files. each
  properties file contains a "platform" property
- or if you are using maven to build your application, you can create
  profiles, to set property/attribute at building time.

...

Comment: -D is for development ? It could be any flag or is this some special flag? System.getProperty("D") ?

Comment: NO. if you type java (Enter) in your command line, and check the output text, there should be one line:` -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property` in your case, the -Dapp.env=TEST for example, could be added to your server (tomcat? weblogic? websphere? ....) start script.  And in your application, you could get systemproperty by name "app.env", to check which environment are you in.

Comment: Ok. Now I am getting it. We are running on Tomcat. I have never deployed an application into production so I would not know, but I am guessing there is a specific way to tell tomcat that we are in production in order for it to stop compiling and other overhead stuff.

Comment: Good answer, however I wouldn't recommend anyone to use the first approach (IP address check), as it renders your application code subject to breakage as a result of changes in networking topology.